# PHP extract data via SQL or PHP?

Tags: php, sql, odbc

I'm working with data bases using PHP and ODBC driver. And I make a SQL query. Now I need to print the result, but only unique items. As I assume there're two ways: rebuild my query usind `DISTINCT` clause and  rebuild the result array like this: `$uniques = array_unique($result, SORT_REGULAR);`
And now I'm confused about what way is more correct (in terms of data processing or execution time etc.)
Thanks.

*UPD*. I have a **huge** database, but the result could contain < 10 rows

Comment: It is better to fix your SQL query - less data - less execution time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always the best is to optimize your `SQL` query. Using `DISTINCT` you can save the time for bringing the unnecessary records and no need to waste time by removing duplicate using `PHP` too.

Answer (score 1):

For speed and memory efficiency, you want to return the minimum amount from the database without putting unnecessary rows for processing/memory efficiency. So, the distinct in this case is the better choice.